# I'm looking for the descriptive word of small group with a special language

Tags: single-word-requests

This word refers to the special language a family or group of children would use to communicate with each other.

I thought it was sartorial, but that is about clothing choices or tailoring.

It was used to describe a large family's special language that others could not easily understand. For example in my family we used the word plogged up to describe a clogged or plugged drain and the like.

Comment: How about [family slang](https://www.thoughtco.com/family-slang-term-1690854#:~:text=The%20informal%20term%20family%20slang,family%20words%2C%20and%20domestic%20slang.)? Other terms thrown up by Google are _family jargon_ and _familects_.

Comment: Our family uses idiosyncratic words; More Intriguing: Our team uses cabbalistic language to discourage spies!

Answer (score 2):

The most relevant and appropriate word has a syllabic rhyming similarity (which may explain your confusion) to your first thought of “sartorial”. It is **argot**.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/argot)
> *argot*
> words and expressions that are used by small groups of people and that are not easily understood by other people

Another weaker possibility might be **jargon**, which also has the rhyming similarity, but usage and the definition associate this word with work groups rather than other groups.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jargon)
*jargon*
special words and phrases that are used by particular groups of people, especially in their work

Comment: I believe _lingo_ is even more appropriate for the jargon of small groups but their use is inconsistent. [_Dictionary.com_](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lingo) definition: "the language and speech, especially the jargon, slang, or argot, of a particular field, group, or individual". _Argot_ is usually used as a secret language to exclude outsiders.